# Advanced model_set.count in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, filter, count

I know e.g. `object.poll_set.count`, but how can I filter these, so I only get the count of some of the objects i poll_set. I mean something like `object.poll_set.filter(pk<20).count`. I guess I have to do it in the logic instead of the presentation, but what is the preferable way to do it?

I also need to find 'the nested count' of some objects. I have three models (model 1, model 2, model 3). Model 3 has a FK to model 2, and model 2 has a FK to model 1. In model 1 I can get the number of records from model 2 which refers to model 1, but I also need the number of records from model 3 which refers to any object in model 2 which refers to the specific object in model 1.

I print the objects from model 1 in a ListView. How can I get the total number of records in model 2 which refers to any object in model 1, i.e. a grand total of the number of objects I've found in each object. Should I count this in my loop in the template and print it in the `<tfoot>`?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `object.poll_set.filter(pk__lt=20).count()`. Django uses special names for comparing values like `__lte`, `__iexact` etc. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups . This has been in Django since the very first versions.

Don't count inside a loop because you may have a lot of unneccessary database lookups.
So when you have two models: Model1 (parent), Model2 (child) and want to see every Model1 with the number of Model2 attached, you do `Model1.objects.filter(whatever).annotate(model2_count=Count('model2'))`

EDIT: to clarify where the custom count functionality should be

your view might look like this:

views.py

```
def model1_list(request):
  objects = Model1.objects.all().annotate(model2_count=Count('model2'))
  return TemplateResponse(request, 'your_template.html', {'objects':objects})
```

and your template "your_template.html":

```
{% for o in objects %}
  <b>{{ o }}</b> - model2s: {{ o.model2_count }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. With `object.poll_set.filter(pk<20).count` I meant as a template tag. Can I find an equivalent to your example in the template engine?

Comment: No. The template language is stupid by design. For logic you should use your views that you program in python.

Comment: Okay. What is the best way to define this custom count-function? A templatetag? A model function?